Viewing attachments in Xcode 15.3 with test plans
Using Xcode 15.3 when running a UITest, I take a screenshot
  let screenshot = XCUIScreen.main.screenshot()
  let attachment = XCTAttachment(screenshot: screenshot)
  attachment.lifetime = .keepAlways
  add(attachment)

Looking at the test report, I see
t =     2.59s Added attachment named 'Screenshot of main screen (ID 1).png'

so the screenshot is being taken, but there is no sign of an attachment link or any other linkage.
If I go to the derivedData volume and open the relevant xcresult package, there is a Data folder but no Attachment folder.
If I go to the app.xctestplan configuration then under 'UI Testing', I have
Automatic Screen Capture - On, keep all
Preferred Capture Format - Screenshot
Localisations Screen Shots - On

under 'Attachments' I have
Attachments - On, keep all

so where are the attachments being stored? I also note that this apple developer page should be marked as deprecated.
